# Deserialize Json Object having double quoted string

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, jsonconvert

I want to deserialize a JSON string that has double quoted string as mentioned below.

Json:

```
string jsonString = "{\"Name\": 2, \"Description\": \"The \"test\" description\"}";
```

Target Class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization Code:

```
string jsonString = "{\"Name\": 2, \"Description\": \"The \"test\" description\"}";
var jData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(jsonString);
```

I am not able to escape the double quotes and having the following error.

[image]

Comment: That is invalid JSON.

Comment: The string is fetched from request parameter where user can enter text with double quotes.

Comment: granted, but it is returning malformed invalid JSON

Comment: Are you in control of where the string is fetched from? Because that is where the problem originates. It needs to properly escape those characters.

Comment: Yes. Data is entered in Text box and I am using 'FormCollection' to access the data.

Comment: @Anadi were you able to solve this because i am having same issue.

Comment: @Nkosi How can i properly escape this kind of data.